# Eloquent Javascript - correlation and coefficient

Tags: javascript, correlation, coefficients

Currently I'm reading **Eloquent Javascript** book and at **chapter 4**. This topic entitled '**The lycanthrope’s log** ' is very confusing  to me. How important is **correlation and coefficient** in real world programming?

I'm trying to understand the formula used to  find correlation. I've far forgotten maths since I left my high school. Could, someone who've read this book, **explain to me in detail**, please? Below is the picture I'm wondering about..
[image]

Comment: He gave this example just to show how to set and retrieve data in objects. I believe it's a better idea asking this in statistics SE community. Regarding your question: it depends on what are you programming. Just the other day I wrote a code that uses Pearson's correlation coefficient... I searched online and found what i needed to build the function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, could you provide the link for statistic SE community?

Comment: Here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, thanks posted there..

Comment: @112233 Did u find out about ut answer. I am also studying same book and confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is actually pretty straight forward. Consider the table from your question.

> The table states that there were a total **90 observations**

Out of all 90 observations:

1. **76 times**, no pizzas or squirrel
2. **9 times**, pizzas but no squirrel
3. **4 times**, squirrel but no pizzas
4. **1 time**, both squirrel and pizza

> So we want to find out how **Pizzas** & **Squirrels** are related:

---

Consider the equation along with your table now,

(since squirrel is on the left)

#### n00 denotes an observation where there was **no squirrel or pizza** (1)

#### n01 denotes an observation where there was **no squirrel but pizza** (2)

#### n10 denotes an observation where there was **squirrel but no pizza** (3)

#### n11 denotes an observation where there was **both squirrel but pizza** (4)

---

*Now that we know what these values are, let's plug them in to our formula* -

```
correlation = (1×76 - 4×9) / √(5×85×10×80)
```

Comment: "out of all 90 observations"

Comment: "out of all 90 observations" http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.htm I don't know where you're seeing these 90 observations but they aren't here. Even if they are somewhere else, it's super confusing they're not on this page.

Comment: Also you didn't explain the bottom portion of the equation.

Comment: @xckpd7 the 90 observations is represented diagrammatically in the image itself. "No Squirrel, no pizza ~> 76... etc"